# how to fix the forms in vb.net solution explorer

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm working on a project in vb.net with vs2017
so I don't know what happened where I try to open some forms and folders but it doesn't open
although I can see the codes but I can't see the visual form

[image]

Comment: Folder structure looks a mess. You have that excluded `Teachers_Payments` folder under the `Wallet` folder but you also have an included folder with the same name and the same types in it at a different level. You also have a `TeachersPlus` folder in the e4xcluded folder and another with the same name at a different level. Decide what folders and types should be there and which shouldn't and get rid of the ones that shouldn't.

Comment: It looks like you may have copied and pasted the folder `Teachers_Payments` in Explorer, but didn't Include/exclude things properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you are having the issue with the items that show a dashed outline icon.  This indicates that they have been "Excluded from Project".  Entire folders or individual Forms can be excluded.  Based on the image, the entire folder "Teacher Payments" has been excluded from the project.  Excluded items are not compiled.

To correct the issue, right click on the "Teacher Payments" folder and select "Include in Project".